# Sequential number sequence with no repeat from class

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a class:

```
public class User{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int SeqNumber {get;set;}
}

public List<User> UserClass {get;set;}
```

And for a dynamic example,I have 10 Users.  Each SeqNumber is unique, from 1 to 10, based on the amount of Users.  The SeqNumber will be used to order the users in ascending order.  However, the SeqNumber must be unique, and remain within the scope of the amount of Users.

```
UserClass = new List<User>() {
     new User({Name = "Rose", SeqNumber = 1}),
     new User({Name = "Ryu", SeqNumber = 2}),
     new User({Name = "Sagat", SeqNumber = 3}),
     new User({Name = "Dhalsim", SeqNumber = 4}),
     new User({Name = "Zangief", SeqNumber = 5}),
     new User({Name = "Ken", SeqNumber = 6}),
     new User({Name = "Chun-Li", SeqNumber = 7}),
     new User({Name = "Vega", SeqNumber = 8}),
     new User({Name = "Balrog", SeqNumber = 9}),
     new User({Name = "M. Bison", SeqNumber = 10}),
};
```

Let's say someone decides to change Ryu's SeqNumber to 6, as an example of usage. Sagat's  will move to 2, Dhalsim's will move to 3, Zangief's will move to 4, Ken's will move to 5.
Inversely, what if I move M.Bison's SeqNumber to 2? The other User's SeqNumber should increment by 1. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: SeqNumber is a sort order to be used elsewhere.  Numbers cannot be identical based on database schema.

Comment: It's just that I'm not exactly sure how to word the question in the title.  Anyone want to help me with that?

Comment: I think the problem is not so much the title of the question, it is that it's very hard to understand what you want to do.  Guffa's answer below will address the very specific case you have outlined but I suspect you have a more general case that is difficult to infer from the information you have provided.

Comment: I think I've worded my wants a bit more clearly.  Does it help understand what I want to do?

Comment: If you had a `List<string>` you could use [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the zero-based index of a (unique) entry. You would need to use `Remove` or `RemoveAt` and `Insert` to change the index/sequence number of an item by moving it within the list.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to role the sequence numbers in that way, if the only requirement is to keep them unique then in your example the simplest solution would be when changing Ryu's SeqNumber to 6, change Ken's to 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do this by using the following extension method which makes use of the indexer in a list:

```
public static void MoveAndRecalculateSequence(
    this IList<User> users, int moveFromIndex, int moveToIndex)
{
    // Capture a reference to the user we want to move.
    var user = users[moveFromIndex];

    // Remove it from the list at it's current index.
    users.RemoveAt(moveFromIndex);

    // Insert the user at the required destination.
    users.Insert(moveToIndex, user);

    // Recalculate the seq number using the index of the list.
    for(int i = 0; i < users.length; i++)
    {
        users[i].SeqNumber = i + 1;
    }
}
```

And use it as such:

```
// remember indexes start at 0 in C#
users.MoveAndRecalculateSequence(1, 5);
```

Answer (score -1):

Put your users in the list, so that you can access them dynamically:

```
UserClass = new List<User>() {
  new User({Name = "xxxx", SeqNumber = 1}),
  new User({Name = "xxxx", SeqNumber = 2}),
  new User({Name = "xxxx", SeqNumber = 3}),
  ...
};
```

Now you can get the users that should have their `SeqNumber` property changed, i.e. the ones with the number 2 to 6, and set the new values for them:

```
UserClass
  .Where(u => u.SeqNumber => 2 && u.SeqNumber <= 6)
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(u => {
    if (u.SeqNumber == 2) {
      u.SeqNumber = 6
    } else {
      u.SeqNumber--;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.